# Change the footer in a site that is using Plone 5

Tags: plone, footer

I would like to change the footer on my site that is using Plone 5. The current footer has the Powered by Plone link in it and I want to remove it and replace it with a link of my own choosing. I am not sure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Change the FooterPortlets with your own e.g. a Static Text Portlet with your Text and Links. In the Sidebar you find the "Manage Portlet" Option.

The "Powered by Plone" section is given by the "colophon" portlet that you can hide or delete.